# How can I export all products that have no images?

Tags: magento-1.9, products, export

I need to export all products without images in my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to `system > import/export > Dataflow Profiles` > you can  see `Export al Products` option > click on that , than go to `Run profile` , than click on `Run profile in pop up` , than check var/export folder , you can see file with all products.

**Edit**

if you look at the excel sheet , which contains columns of only images. you can observe the blank values in some fields, those products not have images.

Comment: i need only export which product has no images

Comment: check my update.

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to write a custom module or need to filter the product collection which don't have images.

```
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter(array(
        array (
            'attribute' => 'image',
            'like' => 'no_selection'
        ),
        array (
            'attribute' => 'image', // null fields
            'null' => true
        ),
        array (
            'attribute' => 'image', // empty, but not null
            'eq' => ''
        ),
        array (
            'attribute' => 'image', // check for information that doesn't conform to Magento's formatting
            'nlike' => '%/%/%'
        ),
    ));
```